# add fake obstacle to /obstacle topic used by costmap_2d

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, gmapping, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to add a "fake" or arbitrary obstacle to the /obstacle topic that my real pioneer 3dx is using to navigate.  Is this possible? and if so how? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97451/add-fake-obstacle-to-/obstacle-topic-used-by-costmap_2d/) by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2013-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could create a node that provides a fake point clound describing your obstacle.

---

Originally posted by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) with karma: 1145 on 2013-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-11-04**:
@Hendrik *SeveQ* Wiese thats a good idea how can i manage to do it? do you have any tutorials or links taht could be of help? Thanks

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-11-04**:
Not really, sorry. I guess, you'd have to create the point cloud manually, maybe (in case you only need two dimensions) by linear interpolation between the corners of your obstacle. But don't nail me down on that. I haven't done this before. Someone else could most likely be of better help here...